# multiple and/or conditions is not working in Ci

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, mysqli

I got stuck here ,Its seems like the query is correct ,but I am getting some different result

```html
SELECT `car_id`, `pickup_date`, `pickup_time`, `drop_date`, `drop_time`, `booking_status`, `pickup_seconds`, `drop_seconds`
FROM `car_booking`
WHERE `pickup_seconds` BETWEEN 1484516700 AND 1484606100
OR `drop_seconds` BETWEEN 1484516700 AND 1484606100
AND `car_id` = '14782'
AND `ride_status` != 'completed'
AND `booking_status` != 'rejected'
```

Here I am getting cars ,but whose car_id is not 14782 , no car is there in this id (14782),I am getting other car details .

below is my code

```html
$this->db->select("car_id , pickup_date ,pickup_time ,drop_date ,drop_time,booking_status,pickup_seconds,drop_seconds");

        $this->db->or_where("pickup_seconds BETWEEN $ps AND $ds");
        $this->db->or_where("drop_seconds BETWEEN $ps AND $ds");
        $this->db->where('car_id' , "14782");
        $query1 = $this->db->get_where("car_booking", array("ride_status !="=>"completed","booking_status !="=>"cancelled","booking_status !="=>"rejected"));
```

Can any one suggest me ?

Thank you .

Comment: The query does not look correct, you need braces around the 2 `OR` conditions. No idea how to do that in CodeIgniter though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Codeigniter 3.0 you can use group_start() and group_end(). More info on Query Grouping [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping)

your example could look like this:

```
$query = $this->db    ->select("car_id , pickup_date ,pickup_time ,drop_date ,drop_time,booking_status,pickup_seconds,drop_seconds");

                        ->where('car_id' , '14782')
                        ->where('ride_status !=' , 'completed')
                        ->where('booking_status !=', 'rejected')
                        ->group_start()
                            ->where("pickup_seconds BETWEEN $ps AND $ds")
                            ->or_where("drop_seconds BETWEEN $ps AND $ds")
                        ->group_end()
                        ->get('car_booking');
return ($query->num_rows() ) ?$query->result():false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$where = "(pickup_seconds BETWEEN '.$ps.' AND '.$ds.' or drop_seconds BETWEEN '.$ps' AND '.$ds.' )"; 

$query = $this
        ->db
        ->select("car_id , pickup_date ,pickup_time ,drop_date,drop_time,booking_status,pickup_seconds,drop_seconds")
        ->from('car_booking')
        ->where($where)
        ->where('car_id' , "14782")
        ->where('ride_status !=' , "completed")
        ->where('booking_status !=',"rejected")
        ->get();


        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            return $query->result();            }
        else {
           return null;
        }
```

I think the above code works because this is how i implemented orwhere condition in active record in my CodeIgniter projects since i didnot get expected results with orwhere function of CodeIgniter. If it didn't work please comment the problems below.

Comment: There is a small change in code i return just true but remember to return  $query->result()